# Runspace.Debugger.DebuggerStop event is not fired on Win7

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, powershell, runspace

I'm using this sample https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-PowerShell-f5c03f2d to create my own debugger for powershell 3+. The sample works as expected on Win 8.1 (with Powershell 4) and not on Win 7 with Powershell version 3.
Runspace.Debugger.DebuggerStop event handler is not fired when the breakpoint is hit, but according do MSDN docs, it should work since Powershell 2.
I also tried to update PS to version 4 and then 5, and it's the same.
What could be wrong?

**ADDED INFO:**

Steps to reproduce it:

1. Download that C# sample, open it in Visual Studio
2. Download Windows Powershell SDK and install it
3. Build that project and run it on Win7

-> New console application shows up. This application generates .ps1 file with sample powershell code, sets breakpoint to line 10 and adds event handlers for events BreakpointUpdated and DebuggerStop. It runs that .ps1 file and should jump to debug mode by calling DebuggerStop event handler. But it's not happening.

*Working app on Win 8.1: - breakpoint is hit and custom DebuggerStop event is called*
[image]

*Broken app on 7x64 - breakpoint is not hit*
[image]

Comment: It is not clear what should be done in order to reproduce the problem (or even what the working scenario is).

Comment: Steps to reproduce it:

1) Download that C# sample, open it in Visual Studio

2) Run it on Win7

-> New console application shows up. This application generates .ps1 file with sample code, sets breakpoint to line 10 and adds event handlers for events BreakpointUpdated and DebuggerStop.
It runs that .ps1 file and should jump to debug mode by calling DebuggerStop event handler. But it's not happening.
I will add screenshots to the question.

Comment: I cannot build this sample on Win7 with PS v3 (e.g. `SetDebugMode` is not found). I can build it on Win 8.1 with PS v4. Perhaps this sample is not designed for PS v3.

Comment: That's interesting. It worked for me. If I update System.Management.Automation reference, I have the same issue as you. I have PS v5 installed on my Win7 machine and SetDebugMode method is still not available. Do I need higher Powershell SDK (that was still not released) for this API to be supported? I thought higher PS version is enough.

Comment: It's difficult to tell. I would try to change the original code so it is really v3 compatible. I am almost sure it is doable, I wrote at least 2 PS debuggers in the past, they work in PS 2+ with no issues.

Comment: Here is one my debuggers implemented as a script [Add-Debugger.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShelf/blob/master/Add-Debugger.ps1). Perhaps you even may use it (depending on your scenario).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info and Add-Debugger script.
My scenario: Console app, that can accept powershell cmdlets via TCP connection and invoke them in different thread. Because we have a lot of powershell  2.0 or 3.0 tests that run on virtual machines and I want to be able to remote debug them in case of failure.